# PayTm plugins requires a parameter: MERCHANT_ID, INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID, WEBSITE

Tags: cordova, apk, phonegap, paytm

I want to generate a .apk from phonegap build using cordova. This app includes paytm plugin:

Config xml Paytm plugin:

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-paytm" source="npm" spec="~0.0.6"/>
```

Following function is used to call payTm service:

```
var options = {
              ENVIRONMENT: "staging",
                        REQUEST_TYPE: "DEFAULT",
                        MID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                        ORDER_ID: "ORDER0000000001",
                        CUST_ID: "10000988111",
                        INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail",
                        CHANNEL_ID: "WAP",
                        TXN_AMOUNT: "1",
                        WEBSITE: "WEBSTAGING",
                        CALLBACK_URL: "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORDER0000000001",
                        EMAIL: "user1@gmail.com",
                        MOBILE_NO: "XXXXXXXXX",
                        CHECKSUMHASH: "w2QDRMgp1/BNdEnJEAPCIOmNgQvsi+BhpqijfM9KvFfRiPmGSt3Ddzw+oTaGCLneJwxFFq5mqTMwJXdQE2EzK4px2xruDqKZjHupz9yXev4="
                    };
 paytm.startPayment(app.successCallPayTm, app.failureCallPayTm, options);
```

during phonegap build, it throws the following error:

requires a parameter: MERCHANT_ID, INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID, WEBSITE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the plugin specifing those variables with --variable ?
If not, you should add them manually into your config xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-paytm" source="npm" spec="~0.0.6"/>
   <variable name="MERCHANT_ID" value="yourvalue" />
   <variable name="INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" value="yourvalue" />
   <variable name="WEBSITE" value="yourvalue" />
</plugin>
```

Comment: It works. Now app is properly generated but a transaction is failed and throws the error "Network Not Available".